# How do I fix a Java.lang.StackOverFlow exception?

Tags: java, android, stack-overflow

Im not sure what to do here. I've looked at the logcat cat and I know that its between my MainActivity class and my DrawingTools class. I've also listed the line numbers to help identify which lines are which. My question is how do I fix this error java.lang.StackOverflow?

Here is my Logcat:

```
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504): java.lang.StackOverflowError
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference.add(FinalizerReference.java:48)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at android.os.StrictMode$InstanceTracker.<init>(StrictMode.java:2155)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at android.os.StrictMode.trackActivity(StrictMode.java:1857)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at android.app.Activity.<init>(Activity.java:768)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:13)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.DrawingTools.<init>(DrawingTools.java:9)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testcad.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:22)
07-05 00:55:17.852: E/AndroidRuntime(15504):    at com.example.testc
```

Here is my MainActivity class:

```
13    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
14  
15   Handler uiHandler;
16   EditText cl;
17   TextView info;
18   Button enter;
19   Button line;
20   Button arc;
21   DrawingUtils callDU = new DrawingUtils();
22   DrawingTools callDT= new DrawingTools();
23   EditTools callET = new EditTools();
24   Conversion callConversion = new Conversion();
25   
26  @Override
27  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
28      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
29      setContentView(R.layout.canvas);
30                                                                                                               31 info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);                                                                                             32        enter = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enter);
33       line = (Button) findViewById(R.id.line);
34        arc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.arc);
35        cl = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cl);
36        
37        uiHandler = new Handler() { public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
38       switch (msg.what) {
39        
40        } Bundle bundle = msg.getData(); String string1 =
41        bundle.getString("P1Key"); String string2 =
42        bundle.getString("P2Key"); info.setText(string1);
43        info.setText(string2); } };
44       
45  }
46
47  @Override
48  public void onClick(View v) {
49      switch (v.getId()) {
50      case R.id.enter:
51          String input = cl.getText().toString();
52          synchronized (callDU.string) {
53              String[] In = input.split(",");
54              callDU.setX(In[0]);
55              callDU.setY(In[1]);
56              callDU.setZ(In[2]);
57              callDU.string.notifyAll();
58          }
59
60          break;
61      case R.id.line:
62
63          break;
64      case R.id.arc:
65
66          break;
67      }
68  };
69     }
```

Here is my DrawingTools class:

```
 7    public class DrawingTools {
 8  DrawingUtils callDU = new DrawingUtils();
 9  MainActivity callMain = new MainActivity();
10  public class Line extends Thread {
11      Thread line = new Thread();
12      @Override
13      public void run() {
14          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
15          super.run();
16          //Set Text To (Enter Point 1)
17          Message msg = Message.obtain();
18          Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
19          String setTextP1 = "Enter Point 1.";
20          bundle.putString("P1Key", setTextP1);
21          msg.setData(bundle);
22          //callMain.uiHandler.sendMessage(msg);
23          synchronized(callDU.string){
24              try {
25                  callDU.string.wait();
26              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
27                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
28                  e.printStackTrace();
29              }
30              
31          String X1 = callDU.getX();
32          String Y1 = callDU.getY();
33          String Z1 = callDU.getZ();
34          callDU.point.add(X1);
35          callDU.point.add(Y1);
36          callDU.point.add(Z1);
37          
38          }
39          Message msg1 = Message.obtain();
40          Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
41          String setTextP2 = "Enter Point 2.";
42          bundle1.putString("P2Key", setTextP2);
43          msg1.setData(bundle1);
44          //callMain.uiHandler.sendMessage(msg1);
45          synchronized(callDU.string){
46              try {
47                  callDU.string.wait();
48              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
49                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
50                  e.printStackTrace();
51              }   
52          String X2 = callDU.getX();
53          String Y2 = callDU.getY();
54          String Z2 = callDU.getZ();
55          callDU.point.add(X2);
56          callDU.point.add(Y2);
57          callDU.point.add(Z2);
58          }
59      }   
60  }
```

Comment: What is line 22 of `MainActivity` and what is line 9 of `DrawingTools`?

Comment: **"MainActivity callMain = new MainActivity();"** - Do not do this EVER. You can not create an instance of an Android `Activity` class using `new` - if you attempt to do this regardless of what other problems you may have in your code, your app will crash and burn. Please read about Application Fundamentals at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html and about the Android `Activity` class at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: You can stop stack overflow by avoiding recursion.  Or by not visiting this site. ;)

Comment: Sorry I updated the code with the line numbers i thought i ad put them in already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a circular reference on both classes

DrawingTools class declares a `callMain = new MainActivity();`, which will be created on init

On the other hand, MainActivity class declares `DrawingTools callDT= new DrawingTools();` which will also be provided at init...

In this scenario, one class depend of the other to be constructed, and viceversa.

Comment: Ok, This would create the stackoverflow problem?

Comment: Yes!. I don't know which class you declare first. Let's suppose is MainActivity. By issuing new MainActivity(), an <init> method creates the class and its dependencies.. One of them is DrawingTools callDT. Then the MainActivity<init> will try to create it, so the DrawingTools class will be initialized: DrawingTools<init> will start creating the dependencies, and one of them is MainActivity callMain. At this point, none of the classes have been succesfully initialized, so the process will repeat over and over.. The StackOverflowException is the result of this infinite iteration