# App crashes with java.lang.stackOverflow exception

Tags: java, android, xml

i am developing app in which i am trying to start an Activity named "PensionStatusActivity" from "MainActivity" simply thru Intent.

This is calling line in MainActivity.

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PensionStatusActivity.class));
```

PensionStatusActivity activity populating an XML as it's layout which is as..

**activity_pension_status.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="2sp"
   android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llGo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
            android:paddingLeft="10sp"
            android:background="#D4D8D1"
            android:textColor="#332C2F"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/button_pension_status"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etSamagraIdStatus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/et_back"
            android:paddingLeft="10sp"
            android:imeActionLabel="Done"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="9"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:hint="Samagra ID"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGetStatus"
            android:layout_height="40sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button_go"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:text="स्थिति देखें "/>


            <!--Table View-->
            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tlMemberProfile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:padding="3sp"
                android:background="#D8D8D8"
                android:layout_marginTop="5sp">

                <TableRow
                    style="@style/trSchemesDetail">
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/tvSchemeDetailTable"
                        android:text="Name"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvName"
                        style="@style/tvSchemeDetailTable"
                        />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    style="@style/trSchemesDetail">
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/tvSchemeDetailTable"
                        android:text="Gender"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvGender"
                        style="@style/tvSchemeDetailTable"
                        />
                </TableRow>
                <TableRow
                    style="@style/trSchemesDetail">
                    <TextView
                        style="@style/tvSchemeDetailTable"
                        android:text="Date Of Birth"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tvDOB"
                        style="@style/tvSchemeDetailTable"
                        />
                </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvPensionStatus"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/footer"/>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In PensionStatusActivity i have used below line to populate above xml.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_pension_status);
```

My problem is when control come over this populating line app get crashed. with **java.lang.stackOverFlowException** on Samsung Galexy Tab 4.4 Android OS. While running fine with other devices..

log is as follow

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference.<init>(FinalizerReference.java:42)
    at java.lang.ref.FinalizerReference.add(FinalizerReference.java:54)
    at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.<init>(XmlBlock.java:79)
    at android.content.res.XmlBlock.newParser(XmlBlock.java:72)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:3707)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3440)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1924)
    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:176)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:990)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:930)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3442)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1924)
    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:176)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:990)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:930)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3442)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1924)
    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:176)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:990)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:930)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3442)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1924)
    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:176)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:990)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:930)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3442)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1924)
    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:176)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:990)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:930)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3442)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1924)
    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:176)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:990)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:930)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3442)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1924)
    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:176)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:990)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:930)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3442)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1924)
    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:176)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:990)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:930)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3442)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1924)
    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:176)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:990)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:930)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3442)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1924)
    at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:176)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:990)
    at android.gr
```

Please help what is wrong.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: looks like you are recursivly calling a method `doIt() {doIt();}` which will cause an StackOverFlowException ( can't see which methode it is, so i explained it using a dummy methode `doIt()`)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481445/how-do-i-fix-a-java-lang-stackoverflow-exception?rq=1

Comment: Hey Chirag, thanks for reply, problem has been solved..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to stacktrace, this is a circular reference in your drawable resources. Try to do the following:

1. Comment out all children in your layout.
2. Run ant test. App should work.
3. Uncomment one child view
4. Run and test. If okay, go to the point 3. If not, last added view contains a reference to the broken resource
5. Inspect all drawable resources used by found view

Comment: Hey Dmitry, thanks man, i did the same as you suggested and problem solved. thanks..